# Add a count unique combinations across rows in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, combinations

I am trying to find the unique combinations of the rows and introduce a `count`  column as an `int`. The idea is to find the total number of unique combinations for the data below (ideally in a new dataframe)

| id | cat_1 | cat_2 | cat_3 | cat_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Chips | Null | Null | Null |
| 789 | Chips | Avocado | Null | Null |
| 002 | Chips | Pasta | Null | Null |
| 323 | Chips | Pasta | Null | Null |
| 123 | Chips | Pasta | Cheese | Null |
| 456 | Chips | Sauce | Cheese | Null |
| 101 | Pasta | Null | Null | Null |
| 231 | Pasta | Null | Null | Null |
| 321 | Pasta | Bread | Null | Null |
| 212 | Pasta | Bread | Null | Null |
| 632 | Pasta | Cheese | Null | Null |

I'm imagining the data to look something like this:

| id | cat_1 | cat_2 | cat_3 | cat_4 | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Chips | Null | Null | Null | 1 |
| 1 | Chips | Pasta | Null | Null | 2 |
| 2 | Chips | Pasta | Cheese | Null | 1 |
| 4 | Chips | Sauce | Cheese | Null | 1 |
| 5 | Chips | Avocado | Null | Null | 1 |
| 6 | Pasta | Null | Null | Null | 2 |
| 7 | Pasta | Bread | Null | Null | 2 |
| 8 | Pasta | Cheese | Null | Null | 1 |

I thought I could use something like below however my data actually has up to seven `cat_7` and wasn't sure if this was the right way

`df1.groupby(['cat_1','cat_2', 'cat_3', 'cat_4']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})`

How can I get it into the format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think yes, you can use:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['id']).tolist()
#should working like
#cols = ['cat_1','cat_2', 'cat_3', 'cat_4', 'cat_5', 'cat_6', 'cat_7']
df = df.groupby(cols, sort=False).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
   cat_1    cat_2   cat_3 cat_4  count
0  Chips     Null    Null  Null      1
1  Chips  Avocado    Null  Null      1
2  Chips    Pasta    Null  Null      2
3  Chips    Pasta  Cheese  Null      1
4  Chips    Sauce  Cheese  Null      1
5  Pasta     Null    Null  Null      2
6  Pasta    Bread    Null  Null      2
7  Pasta   Cheese    Null  Null      1
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for the response. I think the challenge is that when i do this like df = ```df.groupby(['cat_1','cat_2', 'cat_3', 'cat_4', 'cat_5', 'cat_6', 'cat_7'], sort=False).size().reset_index(name='count')``` on my data - it returns me only the row that has values in all ?

Comment: @Tim - Do yo uneed remove rows with only `NaN`s in categories or not?

Comment: No - its any row.

Answer (score 1):

#### `DataFrame.value_counts`

```
df.drop('id', axis=1).value_counts(dropna=False).reset_index(name='count')
```

---

```
   cat_1    cat_2   cat_3 cat_4  count
0  Chips    Pasta    Null  Null      2
1  Pasta    Bread    Null  Null      2
2  Pasta     Null    Null  Null      2
3  Chips  Avocado    Null  Null      1
4  Chips     Null    Null  Null      1
5  Chips    Pasta  Cheese  Null      1
6  Chips    Sauce  Cheese  Null      1
7  Pasta   Cheese    Null  Null      1
```